# describe when data is value_counts

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame that contains two columns value, count. For example a row that has (value, count)=(2, 1000) this means that the value 2 occurence 1000. I want to compute min, max, median, percentiles so that the results would be the same as df.describe() when the data is not "grouped"

Thank you

could not find anything

Comment: if you have already grouped the data, I don't see how you can create summary statistics without ungrouping it. Unless you mean you want to output like the min(COUNT) or something

Comment: oh I don't want the min(count) I want summary stats on the values.

Comment: then you cannot accomplish what you want. You have already summarized the values by grouping them together into value counts. In order to do a describe on them (which is a way of summarizing data), you need the raw values

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can have a look at the example provided by @mozway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic way would be to restore the original data, then compute the statistics:

```
# aggregated data
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1, 2, 3], 'count': [5, 1, 4]})

# replicate rows and compute statistics
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['count']), 'value'].describe()
```

Of course, you can do better depending on which exact statistics you want to compute: `min`/`max` would be unchanged; `mean` and `std` could be computed using [`numpy.average`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.average.html)/[`statsmodels.stats.weightstats.DescrStatsW`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.DescrStatsW.html) and their `weight` parameter, etc. You have to see for yourself what you need to compute and decide if you can do so without unaggregating.

Output:

```
count    10.000000
mean      1.900000
std       0.994429
min       1.000000
25%       1.000000
50%       1.500000
75%       3.000000
max       3.000000
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: it does the job but when you have billions of rows it's not scalable I would say. There should a better solution with cum sum and don't see why pandas did not take into consideration

Comment: `cumsum` won't help, and I showed you solutions to avoid duplicating the rows for mean/std, it all depends on which parameters you want to compute. It's not available from scratch in pandas (the *why* is irrelevant here).